# iOS Google map not loading in device always

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

Integrated google maps with ios device
Sometimes google map is blank in iOS device.
But majority of times its visible.
Is this due to poor network connection?

Comment: Assuming you're talking about the Google Maps from Google, yes, a poor/no internet connection *could* be the reason for the blank screen. However, when the internet connection is restored, the map should start loading and showing up.

Comment: @BjornB. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: A better internet connection.

Comment: @BjornB. !! :D 

V1992 Have you tested the GoogleMap App on the side, to see what happens.

Because even with a bad connection, unless you are offline - you should receive something after a while. In this case, check request timeout in your app, or potential race conditions.